# Building an ubuntu docker image

Tags: docker

I am completely new to docker... But I want to do the following..

```
1) git clone git_repo
2) sudo apt-get install dependencies
3) cd to clone repo and do ./compile --flags=true
    make
     make install
4) Then curl filename -o output folder
5) tar xvf /path/to/curl_folder/filename.tar
```

And thats it. I am going thru the documentation but I am still lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article about How to clone a private git repo from a docker container: http://slash-dev-blog.me/docker-git.html  This will help with your step 1 and step 2.

To complete step 3-5, you can add the followings to your Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR  /path/to/clone/repo
RUN ./compile --flags=true
RUN make
RUN make install
RUN curl filename -o output_folder
RUN tar xvf /path/to/curl_folder/filename.tar
```

---

Once you have your Dockerfile ready, you can build an image from the Dockerfile. Here is the tutorial of creating an image from a Dockerfile, http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/#creating-our-own-images

Hope this helps. Pls let me know if you need more help